# RxJS filter function not narrowing type unless directly given a typeguard its the only parameter

Tags: typescript, authorization, observable, typechecking, typeguards

I have been working on an auth service that uses an rxjs behavior subject to store the last retrieved auth object, and triggers a re-fetch if it has expired (or has not been fetched at all yet).

My question is about the TypeScript type checker. I have written the typeguard `isNotUndefined` that asserts - well, exactly what you would expect.

```
export function isNotUndefined<T>(input: T | undefined): input is T {
  return input !== undefined;
}
```

I've already had to write the above typeguard rather than being able to rely on `auth !== undefined`. I now can't for the life of me understand why, in the pipe in `authGetter$` in the code below, the type of the value in the pipe is not reduced down to just `Auth` after the first filter. Instead, the type is still `Auth | undefined`, and it requires the second filter with just the type guard to get the type narrowed down to just `Auth`.

So in summary, why do I need the second filter to narrow the type to just `Auth`? In addition, because I am coding on my own with nobody reviewing it, I would greatly appreciate anyone pointing out 'code smells' they recognise (with suggestions on what do to instead).

```
export default class AuthService {
  private static lastAuth$ = new BehaviorSubject<Auth | undefined>(undefined);

  private static authGetter$ = AuthService.lastAuth$.pipe(
    filter(auth => {
      if (isNotUndefined(auth) && auth.expiry > new Date()) {
        return true ; // identical resulting type with "return isNotUndefined(auth);"
      } else {
        // retry if auth doesn't exist or is expired
        AuthService.authorise().then(newAuth =>
          AuthService.lastAuth$.next(newAuth)
        );
        return false;
      }
    }),
    tap(v => {}), // typechecker says "(parameter) v: Auth | undefined"
    filter(isNotUndefined),
    tap(v => {}) // typechecker says "(parameter) v: Auth"
  );

  static getAuth$(): Observable<Auth> {
    return this.authGetter$.pipe(first());
  }

  private static async authorise(): Promise<Auth> {
    // auth code goes here (irrelevant for this question)...
    // typecast dummy return to make typechecker happy
    return Promise.resolve(<Auth>{});
  }
}
```

I attach a photo of my code in nice syntax highlighting for your viewing ease and pleasure :)

[image: my code in nice syntax highlighting]

Comment: Your `lastAuth$` is defined as `<Auth | undefined>` as that is what you are ultimately returning from `AuthService.lastAuth$.pipe(filter(...))`.

Comment: Yes but with the first filter in the pipe I'm blocking the case of <undefined>, leaving just <Auth> as the only other option in the union type, for the data in the pipe after the first filter, no?

Comment: Not in this case. You are still returning the union type that is defined on `new BehaviorSubject<Auth | undefined>`. Your type guard my need to be put somewhere else where it needs to check if there is `Auth` or possibly try `.map` instead of `.filter` to produce  the `Auth` type

Comment: If you know where to put the type guard to make it work, or if you know why it can't infer a type subset based on the if statement flow analysis, put it in an answer!

Comment: You shouldn't define your BehaviorSubject with the type `<Auth | undefined>`. It doesn't make sense because you can still call `.next()` with `null` or `undefined` even if it's defined as `<Auth>` only. This will for sure lead to type issues in your pipeline because you won't be able to assert that your value is not undefined unless you explicitly define the type with `tap((a: Auth) => ..)`. But you really should not be doing that in your case.

Comment: @Reqven I can't assign undefined without the union type as I have strict-null-checks enabled

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[User-defined type guard functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) are, at least currently, strictly user-defined.  They are not inferred automatically by the compiler.  If you want a `boolean`-returning function to behave as a type guard with a type predicate return type, you need to annotate explicitly it as such:

```
const doesNotPropagate = <T>(x: T | undefined) => isNotUndefined(x);
// const doesNotPropagate: <T>(x: T | undefined) => boolean
```

The function `doesNotPropagate()` behaves the same as `isNotUndefined()` at runtime, but the compiler does not see it as a type guard anymore, so if you use it as a filter you won't eliminate `undefined` in the compiler.

There are multiple issues in GitHub about this; the currently open issue tracking propagating/flowing type guard signatures is [microsoft/TypeScript#16069](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16069) (or possibly [microsoft/TypeScript#10734](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16069)).  But it doesn't look like there's much movement here, so for the time being we will need to just deal with the language the way it is.

---

Here's a toy example to play with to explore the different possible ways of dealing with this, since the example code in your question doesn't constitute a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE .  You should be able to adapt these to your own code.

Let's say we have a value `o` of type `Observable<string | undefined>`.  Then this works:

```
const a = o.pipe(filter(isNotUndefined)); // Observable<string>
```

but this doesn't because of the reason listed above... type guard signatures don't propagate:

```
const b = o.pipe(filter(x => isNotUndefined(x))); // Observable<string | undefined>
```

We can regain the type guard signature and behavior if we manually annotate the arrow function like this:

```
const c = o.pipe(filter((x): x is string => isNotUndefined(x))); // Observable<string>;
```

From this you could do extra filtering logic if you want:

```
const d = o.pipe(filter((x): x is string => isNotUndefined(x) && x.length > 3)); 
// Observable<string>;
```

Here the filter checks that the string is defined *and* that its length is greater than 3.

Note that this technically is not a well-behaved user-defined type guard, since they tend to treat `false` results as meaning that the input is narrowed to *exclude* the guarded type:

```
function badGuard(x: string | undefined): x is string {
  return x !== undefined && x.length > 3;
}
const x = Math.random() < 0.5 ? "a" : undefined;
if (!badGuard(x)) {
  x; // narrowed to undefined, but could well be string here, oops
}
```

Here, if `badGuard(x)` returns `true`, you know that `x` is `string`.  But if `badGuard(x)` returns `false`, you *don't* know that `x` is `undefined`... but that's what the compiler thinks.

It's true that in your code you are not really dealing with the situation where the filter returns `false` (I guess the subsequent pipe parameters just don't fire?), so you don't really have to worry too much about this.  Still, it might be better to refactor the code into one correct type guard followed by the non-type-guard filter that does the extra logic:

```
const e = o.pipe(filter(isNotUndefined), filter(x => x.length > 3)); // Observable<string>;
```

This should amount to the same result at runtime, but here the first filter correctly narrows from `Observable<string | undefined>` to `Observable<string>`, and the second filter keeps the `Observable<string>` (and the `x` in the callback is a `string`) and does the extra logic that filters on length.

And this has the extra benefit of not requiring a type annotation, since you're not trying to propagate the type guard signature anywhere.  So this would probably be the method I'd recommend.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Stackblitz link to code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-ztw1by?file=index.ts)

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed answer, I really appreciate it. It also explains a fair bit - I can see really I'm just working with the limitations of typescript.

Comment: There was one thing that I'm still unclear on: you said the reason that the filter function doesn't infer the resulting type was because user typeguards don't propagate. But the same result happens when using `!== undefined`, which is not a user-defined typeguard:

`const o = new Observable<string | undefined>();`
`const a = o.pipe(filter(x => x !== undefined)); // a: Observable<string | undefined>`

Comment: Sure... type guard results never automatically propagate outside the scope they're used in.  That's one reason why you need user-defined type guard functions in the first place (otherwise any function returning `x !== undefined` would automatically act like a type guard on `x`).  Hope that makes more sense.